How to find the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x - 2} -1}$
This one really confuses me because I would THINK that such a simply algebra problem wouldn't be that taxing, but I am missing SOMETHING.
We are working on the composition of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x - 2}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x - 1}$ so $g(f(x)) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x - 2} - 1}$. The question is then what is the domain of the new function?
So, I observe 2 conditions can make an undefined domain: divide by zero and square root of negative number
Divide by zero
x-2 ≠ 0 
x ≠ 2
Square root of negative number
(1/(x-2)) - 1 ≥ 0
1/(x-2) ≥ 1
1 ≥ x-2 ****
3 ≥ x
Okay fair enough BUT I can also see that as x approaches 2 from the left then 1/(x-2) is negative. So there should be a THIRD condition that I am not seeing. Something that ends with x≥2. Thus the correct domain is 
D: 2<x≤3
I am MISSING something and I can't see where. I suspect that it has to do with the multiplication of x-2 (see the ****?). In doing that, I'm assuming that x-2 is non-negative and thus the ≥ doesn't flip to ≤. So, I considered what if it WAS negative, that would be
1 ≤ x-2
3 ≤ x
That just makes no sense. I have NO IDEA what I'm missing. Can someone please show me how to get the extra condition that x≥2?
----------EDIT-------------
With respect to one of the suggestions, we can reformulate the square root as follows
$\frac{1}{x - 2} - 1$ 
$\frac{1}{x - 2} - \frac{x-2}{x-2}$ 
$\frac{1-(x-2)}{x - 2}$ 
$\frac{3-x}{x - 2}$
We now consider two cases where that fraction is positive. Both +/+ and -/-.
3-x≤0 AND x-2≤0 
-x≤-3 AND x≤2 
x≥3 AND x≤2
This integral is infeasible as both conditions cannot exist simultaneously.
3-x≥0 AND x-2≥0 
-x≥-3 AND x≥2 
x≤3 and x≥2 
This interval is feasible and coupled with the x≠2 gives the right answer
------------Edit----------------
I went back to my student and showed him the results of this discussion. At the last second, I found someting essential. I am teaching him the technique of identifying all the cases where the domain is disrupted. There is one more wrinkle which perfectly fixes that technique and reveals that reforming the problem really does make a difference.
$\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{x - 2}}$
$\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{\sqrt{x - 2}}$
In this form, it is clear that there are three conditions:

3-x ≥ 0 because of the square root in the numerator
x-2 ≥ 0 because of the square root in the denominator
x-2 ≠ 0 because of the fraction

Taken that way, we would have arrived at the right domain.

@Atila Correia thanks for adding in the right hypertext. I'm not familiar with that syntax for this site. Why the down votes?

@JyrkiLahtonen my apologies. I guess late last night i missed the "not". I would like to change it, but there seems to be no tage dedicated to the concept of function domain. I'd be gald to have a suggestion.

@JohnOmielan Yes. That is a good answer, although I'm not sure how to guard against that in the future. I could see that it had to remain positive, that's out I worked out the x>=2, but I couldn't see how to get their mathematically. you are basically ignoring more of the equation and focusing on the positive nature of the fraction alone. Would you please write this up as an answer so I can give you the credit?

@BSD As you requested, I've put my comment into an answer. Regarding your statement of "you are basically ignoring more of the equation and focusing on the positive nature of the fraction alone", that's something that at times is required to get a solution, with practice and experience helping to determine when, and how, to possibly do that. Good luck in determining this yourself more easily yourself in the future.

@JohnOmielan Dude, you are so right and I am literally finishing my dissertation right now. That is what makes it so frustrating that I couldn't see how to get to this mathematically. I suppose I have to agree with a physics PhD I know that said he can do the differential equation, but sometimes can't do the algebra. Hubris will be the death of me.

Since you have $\frac{1}{x−2}\ge 1$, this means $\frac{1}{x−2}$ is positive, i.e., $\gt 0$. As $1$ is positive, i.e., it's $\gt 0$, we must also have $x−2$ being positive, i.e.,
$$x−2 \gt 0 \;\;\to\;\; x \gt 2$$
Also note that this should be determined before the multiplication of both sides of the inequality by $x-2$ is done. That's because with $x−2 \gt 0$, the multiplication is then also valid as you did it. However, with $x−2 \gt 0$ instead, we would get that the inequality would then be reversed, it would then be $1 \le x−2$.

Given that we are dealing with real numbers, we are interested in the solution of:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x - 2} - 1 \geq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{3 - x}{x - 2} \geq 0
\end{align*}
which is is given by $S = (2,3]$.

I'd appreciate more than a hint. I addressed that condition with (1/(x-2)) - 1 ≥ 0.

@BSD when is $\frac{ 3-x}{x-2}$ positive? If +/+ or -/-, right?

Okay, now I see it. I would have appreciated a more complete explanation, but you did give me the critical hint i needed.

@CroCo Yes, I see that too now, but thank you for being more explicit in your comment. I have included that in my full explanation above.
